# New Instagram Graph API - How to get the list of users that liked a certain media

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, mentionapp

I am exploring the new Instagraph Graph API, but I am kinda stucked.

My objective is to get the list of the users that liked a certain media where my business was tagged and / or mentioned.

Any advices?

What I managed to get is the following:
caption
comments
comments_count
like_count
media_type
media_url
owner

Unfortunately, I still haven't found a way to find out who are the actual people who put "like" (or at least from where are these likes coming from).

Thank you very much in advance to you all!

Comment: What do you want with that list?

Comment: What I would like to see is from where these likes are coming from. 

Let me give you a bigger picture: if I launch a contest with my business and I want to reward the people who get more "likes", I want to be sure that no one buys fake likes.
Thus, understanding if a like is coming from my same city and / or country would really help in figuring out if it's genuine

Comment: I need this for a client as well. The older Instagram API Platform will be deprecating starting july 21 2018 and complete deprecation early 2020.

Comment: Looking for this too - though even if you got the list, you may only get the IDs of the users. Hopefully the name would come with it, since the new Graph API doesn't allow querying of the actual profile data.

Comment: Any updates on this, did you manage to get the list of users who liked a media?

Comment: Unfortunately I never got a solution for it  :(